# Android listview showing empty data until keyboard is shown?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I'm using a listview with custom list adapter.

When I clicked "+" button, a list item will dynamically added. Every list item contains 4 EditTexts.

First list item is showing correct data, but other items' rightmost EditTexts are empty.

**This is the issue**

[image: issue image]

you can see last edit texts showing empty data except first list item. This issue is solved after keyboard is shown.

**After opening soft keyboard**

[image: Solved image]

I tried using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` and `list.invalidateViews()`, but now worked.

How can i solve this ?

**onCreate()**

```
Vector v;
CreateExerciseAdapter adapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_workout);

        v = new 
        adapter = new CreateExerciseAdapter(v,this);

        txtName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView2);

        //listview footer button (Add new button)
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        View inflate = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_exercise_item, null);
        ImageButton btnAddNew = (ImageButton) inflate.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonAddNew);
        list.addFooterView(inflate);

        btnAddNew.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                View item = LayoutInflater.from(view.getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.create_new_exercise_item, null);
                v.add(item);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Thank you :-)

**Update**

**Adapter**

```
public class CreateWorkoutListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;
    Vector vector;
    LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    FontManager fm;

    public CreateWorkoutListAdapter(Context context, Vector vector){
        this.context = context;
        this.vector = vector;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return vector.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return vector.elementAt(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_new_exercise_item, null);

        final EditText txtName = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextExerciseName);
        final EditText txtReps = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextReps);
        final EditText txtMin = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextMin);
        final EditText txtSec = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextSecond);


        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is "v"? Please post the adapter code as well.

Comment: @NIkaKurdadze : Thank you. I updated question

Comment: Can you talk about the issue in more detail? Is the added item shown? What do you exactly mean in "This issue is solved after keyboard is shown."?

Comment: @NikaKurdadze : I added screenshots. I think now the issue is clear.

Comment: Do you set the EditTexts' texts somewhere in your code or they are just defined in the xml?

Comment: They are defined in xml

Answer (score 0):

Please replace your getView with the following :

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.create_new_exercise_item, viewGroup, false);

        final EditText txtName = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextExerciseName);
        final EditText txtReps = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextReps);
        final EditText txtMin = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextMin);
        final EditText txtSec = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editTextSecond);


        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Nika. I'll try that

Comment: I tried your answer, but not worked. Then i found the problem. I uninstalled apk file from my device and run the project. It worked fine. I think the problem was this the running process of new Android Studio. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think this answer should be flagged ??

Comment: I'm glad you fixed the problem. I believe this answer should not be accepted, as it was not a solution for your particular issue.

Comment: Yeah. I'm sorry about that. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Changes :

```
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.yourlistviewid);
```

Insted of :

```
list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.
```

Comment: I'm sorry, That's a mistake. I edited question. Sorry

Comment: Please complete your answer.